# c program binary cannot run in sh

Tags: c, bash, binary, sh

I have cross-compiled an executable from c code for an arm-based embedded system. When I execute the binary in the embedded system, it gives the following error:

```sh
line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

I searched around, and figured out it is because the embedded system (some version of Linux) I am using does not have `bash` but only `sh`.  Is it possible to make my compiled binary executable using `sh`, without installing bash in it (which is troublesome)?

Comment: Err, if you have a compiled binary, why does `sh` even parse it?

Comment: To explicit @JCWasmx86's comment I guess you tried to execute`./myprog.c` instead of `./myprog_bin`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!  I was executing `./myprog_bin` instead of `./myprog.c`.  Even a simple one hello world program has such issue.

Comment: It could be an error the shell script; it would help if you could add that to your question

Comment: It turns out I am not using the right toolchain. Thank everyone!

Comment: @skyuuka : Obviously your binary is not recognized as such. Do a `file myprog_bin` to find out what the operating system thinks the file is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binaries are not built for the shell program. They are built for a particular architecture and OS environment. All shell does is, `fork()` a child process and calls `exec()`. So it won't matter whether your host machine is having `bash` or `sh`. Just make sure that binary is for the correct architecture and the machine. And you are indeed executing the binary, not the source.